# solr problem to get the field names

Tags: php, object, full-text-search, solr

Ive got a problem. In each document I've got fields: threads.id and posts.id.

I want to get the field name value for them so i can get data from the database.

Between the lines beneath i have marked the lines where i want to get the fields.

But it returns error because they are $doc is object.

How can i get the fields? I have to do it when it iterates the document and not when it iterates the $field and $value.

```
 // iterate document
 foreach ($results->response->docs as $doc)
 {

---------------------------------------
$forum_model->get_country_id_by_thread_id($doc['threads.id']);
$forum_model->get_user_id_by_thread_id($doc['posts.id']);
----------------------------------------

// iterate document fields / values
foreach ($doc as $field => $value)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($field, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8') . "<br />";
    echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8') . "<br />";
    //echo $doc['threads.title'] . "<br/>";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHPDocs I think you want...

```
$threads = $doc->getField('threads.id')
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can use:

```
$value = $doc->fieldname;
```

Alternatively, if your fieldname isn't a legal PHP variable,

```
$field = $doc->getField('field.name');
$value = $field['value'];
```